# Powershell Search ApplicationHost.config file and replace value

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a need to modify the applicationHost.config file located by default at c:\windows\System32\inetsrv\config.

Reviewing the XML file, there are many entries for location under configuration.  I need to modify only a specific one.  Perhaps checking if it exists first before modifying it?

The following XML is what I want to modify.  The  is nested under the top level configuration.  I want to change just one entry, anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" if found to be false.

```
<location path="Default Web Site/MyWebsite/SiteA">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

A side note.  I do see that I could use set-webconfigurationproperty.  However, when I do so, it tells me the configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.  I'm using PSPath, which is supposed to get around that, but it's not working.

Comment: Regarding your side note, you might need to go in Feature Delegation of your IIS server (inetmgr.cpl) and set Authentication - Anonymous to Read / Write then attempt again to use ```set-webconfigurationproperty```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.
I recommend you create a backup copy of your Applicationhost so you can revert should need arise.

You'll need to run that script as administrator.

The trick is to leverage `SelectNodes` or `SelectSingleNode` and target the specific nodes you are interested in. I used your provided code to specify I was looking for the node you were interested in but only where the location path corresponded to "Default Web Site/MyWebsite/SiteA"

```
$InetConfigPath = 'c:\windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config'
$xml = [xml](get-content -Path $InetConfigPath -Raw)


$Nodes = $xml.SelectNodes('//location[@path="Default Web Site/MyWebsite/SiteA"]/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication')
foreach ($Node in $nodes) {
    if ($Node.enabled -eq $false) {
        $Node.enabled = 'true'
    }
}


$xml.Save($InetConfigPath)
```

- WebAdministration module is recommended over modifying the ApplicationHost.config file directly to avoid unintended consequences.

**References**

[Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation)

Comment: Yes, thank you!  Apologies, I missed that there was a reply to my question.  I ended up using the WebAdministration module, as it seemed much safer for this file.